# Possible to use Manipulate in GUIRunModal?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, scripting

Is it possible to use the widget created by `Manipulate` within `GUIRunModal`? I intend to run the file using `MathematicaScript -script <filename>`.

Comment: You want to run it from the command line _and_ use a manipulate?

Comment: What you ask for is not possible, but if you explain why you want to do this, there may be an alternative solution.

Comment: What I intended to do was create a command-line tool that launched a window that used System`Dump`showStringDiffs to diff two strings. I thought that Manipulate would allow me to provide two input fields, for the strings, and show the output of the diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  `Manipulate` only works in a notebook, opened in the Front End, because it relies on Front End functionality.  `GUIRunModal` uses Java to display a GUI, not the Front End.

It is not possible to use `Manipulate` without the Front End (or CDFPlayer).